# Thymeleaf Configuration - Not able to import org.thymeleaf.spring4.*

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf in my spring-boot web-application, and I am trying to use the already provided functionalities of the Thymelief for a Spring Boot project. But, I am not able to import the org.thymeleaf.spring4.* - actually, spring4 is not recognized at all. I am using Thymeleaf 3.0.11.

Actually, in my project, gradle is used as a build automation tool, and Thymeleaf is added as in the following (in a multi-module Spring Boot application, and this gradle file corresponds to the module where the Thymeleaf template engine is configured):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
 ...

        dependencySubstitution {
    ...

            substitute module('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf') with module('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.0.11.RELEASE')
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any idea about the reason of this is happening?

Comment: Check start.spring.io and download the project from there.  You can compare it against your current project if you want to see where you went wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you want spring4 and not spring5?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have added dependency in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. Actually, gradle is used in my project, and this is how it is added:   `...substitute module('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf') with module('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.0.11.RELEASE')` - because sprig-boot pulls in old versions.

Comment: That's the base thymeleaf dependency. You also need the spring dependency

Comment: I assumed spring dependency already existed as it was spring project as said by user in question.